# Will citrus recover from alkaline soil/fruit drop?

Tags: soil, citrus, ph

Recently bought a place with orange, Clementine, lime, grapefruit, and lemon trees. New to growing citrus and did not test soil so did a fantastic job of nearly killing them all. Our soil ph is 8.5, very alkaline. Am adding about 2" of peat moss all around the dripline and will add a light sulfur/water mix but will the trees come back ok for next year? Am I adding enough peat moss, and how often should I add more? Thanks!